# Portlet state is not retained when maximized/minimized

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4, portlet, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 and MVC portlets. I use jsp and extjs to render my portlets. When I maximize/minimize, the current state of the portlet is lost. I would like to retain the state of the portlet even after maximizing/minimizing. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portlet has two phases: action phase & rendering phase. Action phase will be run when some state must be change, eg. when form-submit is done. Rendering phase will be always run, also after maximizing/minimizing.
If you don't want that in rendering phase some state is changed, put this logic to action phase.

By MVC-Portlet you have two methods for handling each phases:

```
public class MyLiferayTestPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        System.out.println("action");
        //here you can change the state
    }

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        System.out.println("rendering");
        //here you can prepaire the rendering of jsp

        //print the window state
        ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        System.out.println("isStateMaximized: " + td.isStateMaximized());
    }
}
```

Here you can read about two phases of portlet:
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/understanding-the-two-phases-of-portlet-executi-4